# Trying to put the code I made that solves Quadratic and Linear equations into a GUI using tkinter. How can I do this?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, quadratic

This is the code I have written. I have attempted to get a GUI that just places the Quadratic and Linear equation into the GUI  so it can be solved in a visual way by the user

```
from tkinter import *
master = Tk()
var1 = IntVar() 
Checkbutton(master, text='male', variable=var1).grid(row=0, sticky=W) 
var2 = IntVar() 
Checkbutton(master, text='female', variable=var2).grid(row=1, sticky=W)
w = Canvas(master, width=40, height=60)
canvas_height=20
canvas_width=200
y = int(canvas_height / 2) 
w.create_line(0, y, canvas_width, y ) 
mainloop() 



from math import sqrt

print("Quadratic function : (a * x^2) + b*x + c")
a = float(input("a: "))
b = float(input("b: "))
c = float(input("c: "))

r = b**2 - 4*a*c
if a == 0:
    x = -c/b
    print("Linear Function: %f"%(x))


elif r > 0:
    num_roots = 2
    x1 = (((-b) + sqrt(r))/(2*a))     
    x2 = (((-b) - sqrt(r))/(2*a))
    print("There are 2 roots: %f and %f" % (x1, x2))
elif r == 0:
    num_roots = 1
    x = (-b) / 2*a
    print("There is one root: ", x)
else:
    num_roots = 0
    print("No roots, discriminant < 0.")
```

Comment: Hi, please state your problem

Comment: Hey, Sorry thought I was clear in what I said. My problem is that I can't figure out how to have the code for the quadratic and linear equations be shown in a UI instead of just the terminal box in VS Code

Comment: Hello. Sorry it is still not clear: Do you want to print text in the UI or draw the function? In either case you should start by a tkinter tutorial or any UI related tutorial: UI applications are event based: user event trigger the next application response. In the above code nothing past the call to `mainloop` will be executed: `mainloop` is an infinite loop waiting for user graphical events to be dispatched to your UI widgets.

Comment: You can use `Label` to show text and the quadratic equation, use `Entry` widget for inputs.  Then use a button to trigger a function to solve the equation and update the result `Label`.